# MVC else if not triggering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using MVC5 razor and i have am currently making a user profile/account page. I can only seem to get it to trigger if the Session Value is null. But when i have information that it should be getting, it just doesn't trigger.

```
<div id="sidePanelBar">
    @{
        if (Session["CustomerRole"] == null)
        {
            <text>no Customer is logged in</text>
        }
        else if (Convert.ToString(Session["CustomerRole"]) == "user")
        {
            <text>Standard User</text>
        }

        else if (Convert.ToString(Session["CustomerRole"]) == "admin")
        {
            <text>Administrator</text>
        }
    }
</div>
```

I have tried removing teh Convert.ToString, i have tried using a .toString() instead I have also removed the else if and just had 3 separate if statements. everything i try just doesn't seem to trigger. it only triggers if it is null. 
When i debug it it hits this line, But then nothing comes from it, it just skips it as if "user" and "admin" are not there, But they are there if i output the session content into my HTML. so i know for 100% that the session has the role information.

and the following are 3 screenshots:

1) it says no customer is logged in

[image]

2) it doesn't say anything

[image]

3) same spelling as the database entry

[image]

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the lines and see what the value of `Session["CustomerRole"]` is

Comment: Also, where is that session value set?

Comment: session Value is set at login, and it contains "user"

Comment: What happens if you manually set `Session["CustomerRole"] = "user"` just before the `if`? Does it fall withing `else if`?

Comment: What's the type declared on your `Role` column?  Do you need to trim the `Session`'s value?

Comment: There isn't enough info here to help...

Comment: For better readability you can store session value in a `var` and reference the variable in your `if` and `else if`. This will avoid having you to reference `Session["CustomerRole"]` in all your conditional checks.

Comment: @ps2goat I think you solved the issue, When i just trimmed it to 4 characters length and it worked. I think the value in the database was an nChar(15) and i believe it gave it a bunch of white spaces

Comment: Awww... the dreaded "Foo" != "Foo     " problem. Padded database fields are of the Devil ;).

Comment: While this is not your problem, I seriously recommend that you NOT use Session for authorizing the user to various pages.  You should instead be using the built-in Authentication that uses HttoContext.Current.User.IsAuthenticated() or Request.IsAuthenticated()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've reviewed my comment and that fixed the issue, the problem was that your source column for `Role` was an `nchar(15)`.  `char` and `nchar` will pad their values to fill the entire space reserved for the values.  E.g., an `nchar(15)` will always be 15 characters long or null, if nulls are allowed.

Trimming the database value prior to comparing the strings in your code will fix the issue. Either trim your string in code (`myString.Trim()`) or trim it in the database (`LTRIM(RTRIM(role))`).

Unless `char` or `nchar` types are required for legacy support, you should consider changing the column type to `varchar` or `nvarchar`.  Note that you will initially need to trim all the data for that column after changing its datatype, as the whitespace will still exist.

Comment: i just changed it to nvarchar(15) and updated all existing database roles